# So long and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion

Due to [this farewell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/227017) and associated persistent abusive behaviour from SE, I will no longer participate in any sites until such a time as SE becomes less abusive.

My thanks go to all users of this (and other) sites, all the best.

---

Reading some of the comments, I am deeply touched that so many of you valued my input. ***Many thanks indeed.***

Comment: All the best, Sardathrion. Take care, and thanks for the time you spent contributing here.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thank you. It is a shame. I like this community…

Comment: Best wishes to you and hope to see you sometime, when things settle down.

Comment: @Sardathrion I like it too and I can appreciate the difficulty of making that decision. I can totally see where you're coming from; I no longer recognised the company whose service and mission I signed up to participate in.

Comment: I was wondering when we would see the effect of this turmoil here. Thus far RPG has been fairly insulated from it. I respect your decision and wish you all the best going forward. May we meet again under less cloudy skies. Farewell and happy gaming!

Comment: This is a real, material loss for the stack. Farewell, Sardathrion.

Comment: Have a very sad upvote. We'll miss you and your contributions!

Comment: @linksassin I'm not so sure about 'insulated'. As far as I see, all or most of the local big names seem to be aware of the turmoil and the stuff SE keeps doing, but are reacting, on average, differently than the general SE community.

Comment: @vicky_molokh Speaking for myself only, I'm keeping my protests and working towards solutions purposely separate to avoid negatively affecting this community. There's nothing that drama here would accomplish IMO so we try to keep it to a minimum. That doesn't mean pretending nothing is happening obviously. I'm not sure that is different from the average though (or how one would even determine what that average would be). Things like resignations and name changes are more or less outliers in the whole community but much more visible than most other things people can do.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I know anecdotes are not statistics, but anecdotally when browsing other stacks, I got the impression that it's not an outlier to have a noticeable chunk of the big names make at least a symbolic gesture like a name/icon, and of course the list of mod pauses and resignations (with some stacks having no mods left at all) looks imposing. Meanwhile, I have encountered people make much more SE-supporting statements here. But I do accept that my impression may mismatch the greater trend.

Comment: @vicky_molokh Many of the "local big names" and moderators here are well aware of the issues and involved in the discussion on other forums, particularly main meta. But thus far haven't brought it here, that is what I meant by "insulated". This community hasn't really experienced the negative impact of other thus far.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Many thanks for your kind words.

Comment: @Upper_Case Many thanks for your kind words.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Many thanks for your kind words.

Comment: So at last the island of relative calm that was RPG.SE has also succumbed. This hasn't been my main community for probably 4 years now but I still visited and frequently link to existing answers. It was great in its time but the maelstrom around SE/SO has hit us here now, too. Your contributions were both wide and deep. Be well.

Comment: @gomad Thank you for your kind words.

Comment: @Sardathrion-againstSEabuse - Although I haven't experienced too much of this personally, I know it does happen, and it's a **_shame_ in the truest sense of the word**. I hope SE crew can one day figure out ways to _effectively_ deal with the problem (and cease contributing to it, at times). Meantime, **best wishes** and **better roads** to you and to all those who've _just plain had enough_.

Comment: @BrianLacy Thank you for your kind words. It has not affected me personally at all, it is just solidarity and lines crossed…